# What changes when doing a higher level guild quest?

Tags: monster-hunter-4-ultimate

I've been grinding on a guild quest for the Velocidrome to get more marital and the quest started at level 1 and now is at level 29. What exactly changes as the level goes up? I've notice the Velocidrome has gotten slightly harder, but does it give better rewards also?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The monsters in the guild quest will become harder as you clear them each time until the quest reaches LV 140.

LV1-30: Low Rank
LV31-85: High Rank
LV86-125: G Rank
LV126-140:  Super G Rank (need Special G3 Permit to take these on)

monsters at LV140 gets 300% base hp, if you are doing a dual monster guild quest, they are both at 270% as dual monster guild quests get's a -30%hp.

Finally, the reward will also become better, such as better relics and armor spheres at the end.

There's a lot of guides on how to get the most out of expeditions/guild quests if you google them.

Answer (score 0):

From what I have done the reward and difficulty just seem to go up. Not sure if rewards change as all I get are velocidrome and prey stuff. Have gotten some abrasive at end also but no gear yet.